# how to pick required value from data in excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have lot of data in my excel sheet. In cell A I have name of cars with modal and brand name, I want to get brand name in Cell B . Is there any way to do this in bulk?
Here is sample data.

```
"ford mustang gt "
"bmw m5 f10"
"audi tt coupe concept"
"bugatti chiron 2018"
```

So I want data like this in Cell B

```
"ford"
"bmw"
"audi"
"bugatti"
```

Comment: Do you have the collection of brand names that you believe might be in the list

Comment: Will the brand name always be the first word in Cell A?

Comment: @Jordan  .. thanks for reply i was offline for technical issue over here so unable to reply. thanks anyways

Comment: @gowtham shiva .. thanks for reply i was offline for technical issue over here so unable to reply. thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest solutions for your problem is to write the following formula into the column B `=MID(A1,1,SEARCH(" ",A1)-1)`

Like that:

```
+---+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
|   |           A           |              B              |
+---+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
| 1 | ford mustang gt       | =MID(A1,1,SEARCH(" ",A1)-1) |
| 2 | bmw m5 f10            | bmw                         |
| 3 | audi tt coupe concept | audi                        |
| 4 | bugatti chiron 2018   | bugatti                     |
+---+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
```

The point is that this works only if the brand is wrote in the first part of the string (before the first space) and if the brand is only one word long.

A (little) more complicated solution is to have a lookup list of possibile brands and find them into each string, as user @Gowtham Shiva asked in the comment.

Comment: `=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)`